Save colorscheme in session file
Would it possible to save a specific colorscheme in a session file, such that if colorscheme is changed and session file saved, that colorscheme will be loaded next time session file is loaded?
I have a default colorscheme set in 'vimrc'. However, sometimes when I have multiple Vim windows open, I would like to be able to set a particular colorscheme to a particular session file to differentiate the windows when 'Alt-tabbing' among often-numerous open Vim windows (yes, I'm on Windows).
Also, I guess, sometimes I have files opened in a session file that I'd like themed so to speak. Having to set all these files manually to a have a certain colorscheme would be too much work, especially if adding and deleting buffers to session.
I wouldn't mind having to set an autocommand that sets a particular colorscheme when a particular session file is loaded?

Catch SessionWritePost and append any command(s) you need.
augroup foobar | au!
    autocmd SessionWritePost *
        \ call writefile(['colorscheme ' .. get(g:, 'colors_name', 'default')], v:this_session, 'a')
augroup end


That's nice but the only session-related autocommand I can find is sessionloadpost

@Tom You could adapt to SessionLoadPost too but it's better to update Vim, imo.

I'm running 9.1. Just to be sure, I downloaded the latest win64 9.1.0 package and looked at the autocmd.txt doc and nothing in there about SessionWritePost.

@Tom 9.1.0207. "Update" = "git master/HEAD"

I don't think I'm ready to start figuring out how to patch vim but thanks, I learned a bit.

@Tom Prebuilt binaries for Windows are also available.
